# Any way to combine instantiated sprite renderers into one texture so I can apply into a plane at runtime?

Tags: unity, sprites, procedural-generation, tilesets

So I am procedurally generating a tile set in Unity by instantiating different tiles that only have a transform and sprite renderer components. I managed to pack the sprites using unity sprite packer assigning them a packing tag so that I reduce the draw calls drastically.

But Im still having to deal with a great amount of game objects in the scene when the camera zooms out, increasing the batching and giving me problems when I try to apply light to them for example.

So I am trying to find a way to combine all these sprite renderers into a texture.So I can then apply this to a plane and Ill only have to deal with one plane gameObject for the map. But I cant figure out how to do this. I cant really use the combine meshes way as they are sprites only, not meshes. I tried taking a screenshot at run-time but It comes up a bit blurry. Any idea how can accomplish this?
Thank you for your help.

[image: This is is an example of the procedural generation of the tile set]

Comment: Something I've done in the past is set up a tileset texture with all my tile graphics at known grid indices, and a map texture where each pixel's colour value is actually an index into this tileset grid. Then I can use a custom shader to render something on the order of 4096x4096 tiles as a single quad. Would a solution like that be suitable for your use case?

Comment: this should be a good idea but ill have to work on shaders which Im not too familiar with yet but I cant wait to get started with. So from what I can read from your comment basically I can create a texture where I read pixels and each pixel, is one of my tiles? edit didnt mean to press enter. So my tiles they actually have a dimension of 1 unit cube each and the sprite included in each sprite renderer is 16x16 pixels

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to handle it:

- Make a texture that records which tile to draw at each cell of the grid, 1 pixel = 1 tile (so if you make a 4096 square texture, you can have over 16 million tiles in your map)

  - Ensure it's stored uncompressed, with point filtering and no mipmaps
- Write a custom shader that reads this texture for each tile, then looks up the appropriate tile from your tileset texture.
- Render your map as a single quad.

[image: Example showing how a single quad can render a complex tiled map]
For this example I used a [free RPG tileset by Kenney](http://kenney.nl/assets/rpg-base) and a 16x16 map for simplicity.

Here's the shader I used, built on Unity's standard surface shader so I could apply lighting to it:

```
Shader "Custom/TilemapShader" {
    Properties {        
        _MainTex ("Map", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Tileset("Tileset", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Size("Map & Tileset Size", Vector) = (16, 16, 20, 13)
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

        // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        sampler2D _Tileset;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        float4 _Size;
        // _Size.xy is the size of the map in tiles.
        // _Size.zw is the size of the tileset in tiles.

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {

            // Scale up the uvs into tile space.
            float2 mapLocation = IN.uv_MainTex * _Size.xy;

            // Get this pixel's position within the tile we're drawing.
            float2 inTileUV = frac(mapLocation);

            // Clamp the texel we read from.
            // ("Point" filtering does this too, but its math is slightly
            // different, which can show up as a shimmer between tiles)
            mapLocation = (mapLocation - inTileUV) / _Size.xy;

            // Slightly inset tiles so they don't bleed at the edges.
            inTileUV = inTileUV * 126.0f / 128.0f + 1.0f / 128.0f;

            // Calculate texture sampling gradients using original UV.
            // Otherwise jumps at tile borders make the hardware apply filtering
            // that lets adjactent tiles bleed in at the edges.
            float4 grad = float4(ddx(IN.uv_MainTex), ddy(IN.uv_MainTex));

            // Read our map texture to determine what tiles go here.
            float4 tileIndex = tex2D(_MainTex, mapLocation);

            // Generate UV offsets into our tileset texture.
            tileIndex = (tileIndex * 255.0f + inTileUV.xyxy )/_Size.zwzw ;

            // Sample two tiles from our tileset: one base tile and one overlay.
            // (Hey, we have room for two indices, might as well use it!)
            fixed4 base = tex2Dgrad(_Tileset, tileIndex.xy, grad.xy, grad.zw);
            fixed4 over = tex2Dgrad(_Tileset, tileIndex.zw, grad.xy, grad.zw);

            // Combine overlaid tile with base using standard alpha blending.
            fixed4 c = lerp(base, over, over.a);

            // Put all this into terms the Unity lighting model understands.
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;           
            o.Metallic = 0.0f;
            o.Smoothness = 0.0f;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Note that a bunch of the fixups I do there are so that texture filtering works correctly in tileset space. If you're using pixel art tiles with nearest filtering and no mipmaps, you can gut a bunch of that math.

Also, those divisions will be more efficient if you replace them with constants for your map & tileset sizes - I've exposed them as variables here to be more flexible during development & iteration.

If you need to scroll the map over a wider area than you can/want to store in a texture all at once, you can try one of two approaches:

- use one quad & index map for each "chunk" of the map, and recycle/reposition chunks of the map as they scroll off-screen. This requires multiple draw calls, but you can clamp the worst case.
- use one quad for everything shown on-screen, and incrementally update the tile index map as the camera moves around. You can use texture wrapping to pan the map across the quad, so you only have to update a row/column at a time instead of regenerating the whole map.

If you go this route, you'll probably want to also write a script that will generate the tile index map from a source file (like something you created in [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/)), or a custom editor script that helps you modify the tile map visually. Picking precise colour values pixel by pixel to populate the index map was by far the slowest part of putting this example together. ;)

Comment: thats amazing I was working on some quill18create shaders now , so I should be ok Implementing this stuff Ill keep you posted thank you so much for your help. I have been with this problem for a long time

Comment: could I pay you so we could have a quick chat on skype about this question dont know how to pm you to sort this out through stack exchange. Im having a strange bug that when I call set pixels it would show only 8x8 pixels even though I did readpixels for 16x16. this only Happen when I try to double my map size

Comment: For the record, I don't think my employment contract will let me take on work as a paid gamedev consultant outside my studio. ;) But as @Kepazino discovered, my Twitter DMs are open if you have a quick question: `@D_M_Gregory`

Comment: Ok,  I understand I'll try to figure out,  thank you for your altruistic help

Comment: By the way how do I know what color on the tile index map represent a certain tile on the Kenny tileset.  Or what colour do I choose for each tileset  tile

Comment: Red and Green are the x & y indices for the base layer (so 0, 0 is the bottom-left tile, and 1, 2 is 1 right and 2 up from there). Likewise for Blue and Alpha for the overlay layer.

Comment: Ok,  I can also reposition tiles on my tileset source until I achieve the desired tile as well. Omg using shaders the speed of the generation is instant so much quicker than my older approach

Comment: any way to update the shader to lightweight render pipeline? simply is there a way to remove lighting from the shader?

Comment: @Kepol yes. Make an unlit shader graph, and go through each line of code, creating corresponding nodes for each operation, wiring them together as you go.

Comment: How would you implement this with a zoomed in, moveable camera? i.e. Not all tiles are visible at once.

Comment: You don't need to do anything special for that. You can just make one huge plane then zoom your camera in to only show part of it. Tiles that end up off-screen don't need any special handling, because we pay only for the pixels we rasterize. If you want to store just a subset of your tiles in the index map at a time, [you can use a clipmap style approach](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/177398) so you only ever have to update a row or column at a time, rather than shifting the whole texture. Or you can keep a separate index map for each visible chunk.

Comment: This doesn't work for animated tiles. :(

Comment: It can, you just need to post a question explaining your needs and folks can show you a technique to achieve it.