# Unity3D Mapping uv coords from quads with unique vertices directly to texture map

Tags: unity, c#, 3d-meshes, uv-mapping

this is my first post in this stack exchange!

I was wondering how I would go about mapping the texture of my tiles for my tilemap directly to the texture atlas.

I generate the mesh with unique vertices per tile to circumvent having to generate a Texture2D in memory to map all the squares to. I know it's possible to map the uv coords of the vertices to the texture like in the image below, since I have unique vertices per square. But I have no idea how to actually do it in my code. I tried just filling the uv array with random values between 0 and 1 to see if it worked at all but I just get a green mesh, no other colours in there.

[image: Amazing Paint Skills]

Does anyone know a way to implement this?

Comment: Myself, [I like doing this via a tile index texture](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/135307/39518), so I don't need to set up 4 vertices & 6 indices per tile - a single pixel of the index map suffices, and the whole map can be rendered on a single quad.

Comment: Ah that could work, but I want to implement procedural terrain generation as well later on which is why I don't think I can apply that to this usecase

Comment: did you find the answer?